# Set tablet viewport to 1024px, mobile to device width

Tags: css, viewport

I have a responsive site with a desktop width > 980px and a mobile width < 768px. I want tablets to view the site at a 980px viewport, but mobile to view at device width.

Specifically, I want the following:

```
width = device width
if width >= 768px
  viewport = 980px
else
  viewport = width
```

What is the best way to approach this problem? I don't want to check the useragent on the server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // lets push in a viewport 
    var vpw = (screen.width>=768)?'980':'device-width';
    $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="width='+vpw+'" />');

});
```

and from what I tested, that works.  (Which is a bit funny, because the viewport is written after the document 'loaded'; you may see a little jump on screen, and YMMV.)

-- EDIT
nowadays i just write this code in the head, like this

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var vpw = (screen.width>=768)?'980':'device-width';
    document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width='+vpw+'" >');
  </script>
</head>
```

which is what monaca does, so I guess its ok
https://github.com/monaca/monaca.viewport.js/tree/master

Comment: haha well this is the best answer so far. only problem i can think of is when a user resizes above and below 768px.

Comment: add a $(window).resize() and a $(window).orientationchange() to do the same. but at that point, i wonder if the client will honor your change. clearly the specs dont say anything about rewriting viewports dynamically.

Comment: ps .. this is jquery, which you dont necessarily need. its just a lot less typing.

Comment: It's incredibly cool that this works at all, but it's extremely hacky IMHO.  You're dynamically changing the viewport after the document is loaded.  I would not bank on support for this method to be consistent.  That having been said:  I'm going with it for now ;)

Comment: agree. i am nowadays using (modifications of) monaca's viewport.js, and it does the same, but not onload - it writes this codes in the head. much better. let me update my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to accomplish this. In your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

In your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    article {
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}​
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PLrRw/)

Comment: the viewport will still be 768px, so the user will have to manually zoom out

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood your question. You'll probably have to use JavaScript to do that, because the initial-scale depends on the size of the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

in css

```
.container{
   width: 100%;         /* for mobile */
   max-width: 1024px;   /* for pc and tablet */
}
```

the rest css: search media queries ;)

If you have a mobile device, the container width is 100% fullsize. But in pc is the maximal width 1024px. So you can design the rest of your design with css. This needs no javascript or plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { ... }
```

Adjust accordingly. Essentially, this code provides a ceiling and a floor value for that "in the middle" device (like a tablet).

You can tighten that window to force the desktop CSS, or most of it, by doing something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1024px) { ... }
```

Aside from doing something like this, you're going to have to 'sniff' the device, which harkens the 90's (imo -- weren't those the days?), or use the viewport meta data.

Comment: i want the ipad to view the desktop version at 1024px, but in this case, when in portrait it will view it at `@media width: 768px`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a mobile device (not a tablet) has a significantly smaller viewport than 768, why not simply update your media query to apply the change at a smaller size? ie:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

This way your phone styles are only applied to smaller devices with a maximum width of 480px.

Your desktop site (and now tablet) site will still be visible above those resolutions.

Comment: get out of here with your logic.

Comment: Ugh was drunk and selected as answer. Forgot that the iPad still won't see it as 1024px.

Comment: At this point I think I would have to look at your code to see what you mean.

Comment: because @media widht queries depend on the viewport. viewport is set at device width. ipad device width is 768px. i want the ipad to view it at 1024px. this doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Twitter bootstrap scaffolding CSS?  They have pre-built media classes that you can tweak a little bit.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

I think this part most applies to what you are talking about

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px)  { ... }
```

At that point you can use settings to set the fluid span widths to something like below

```
Label               Layout width         Column width     Gutter width
Default             768px and above      42px             20px
Phones to tablets   767px and below      Fluid columns    no fixed widths
```

Note: Since you will be using a fixed column width the div will not scale above the fix column width.

Comment: this has nothing to do with viewports

Answer (score 0):

I also do this whenever a client wants a responsive mobile version but to leave default scaling in place on anything bigger - there's really not much on the web re: setting the viewport tag differently for varying screen sizes, so using JS still seems to be the best option. I specify a non-responsive viewport width by default, e.g.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

then run the following code in the  as soon as possible (i.e. immediately after jQuery has been loaded but NOT wrapped by jQuery's .ready() function or anything equivalent, as the window.screen property seems to be accurate and available immediately. This may avoid the slight jump on mobiles that could occur if the code was run later on):

```
if (window.screen.width < 601) {
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
window.monaca = window.monaca || {};

var IS_DEV = false;
var d = IS_DEV ? alert : function(line) { console.debug(line); };

/**
 * Check User-Agent
 */
var isAndroid = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i));
var isIOS     = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i));

var defaultParams = {
    width : 640,
    onAdjustment : function(scale) { }
};

var merge = function(base, right) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in base) {
        result[key] = base[key];
        if (key in right) {
            result[key] = right[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
};

var zoom = function(ratio) {
    if (document.body) {
        if ("OTransform" in document.body.style) {
            document.body.style.OTransform = "scale(" + ratio + ")";
            document.body.style.OTransformOrigin = "top left";
            document.body.style.width = Math.round(window.innerWidth / ratio) + "px";
        } else if ("MozTransform" in document.body.style) {
            document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + ratio + ")";
            document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "top left";
            document.body.style.width = Math.round(window.innerWidth / ratio) + "px";
        } else {
            document.body.style.zoom = ratio;
        }
    }
};

if (isIOS) {
    monaca.viewport = function(params) {
        d("iOS is detected");
        params = merge(defaultParams, params);
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=' + params.width + ',user-scalable=no" />');
        monaca.viewport.adjust = function() {};
    };
} else if (isAndroid) {
    monaca.viewport = function(params) {
        d("Android is detected");
        params = merge(defaultParams, params);

        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />');

        monaca.viewport.adjust = function() {
            var scale = window.innerWidth / params.width;
            monaca.viewport.scale = scale;
            zoom(scale);
            params.onAdjustment(scale);
        };

        var orientationChanged = (function() {
            var wasPortrait = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight;
            return function() {
                var isPortrait = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight;
                var result = isPortrait != wasPortrait;
                wasPortrait = isPortrait;
                return result;
            };
        })();

        var aspectRatioChanged = (function() {
            var oldAspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            return function() {
                var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                var changed = Math.abs(aspect - oldAspect) > 0.0001;
                oldAspect = aspect;

                d("aspect ratio changed");
                return changed;
            };
        });

        if (params.width !== 'device-width') {
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                var left = orientationChanged();
                var right = aspectRatioChanged();

                if (left || right) {
                    monaca.viewport.adjust();
                }
            }, false);
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                monaca.viewport.adjust();
            });
        }
    };
} else {
    monaca.viewport = function(params) {
        params = merge(defaultParams, params);
        d("PC browser is detected");

        monaca.viewport.adjust = function() {
            var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            var scale = width / params.width;
            zoom(width / params.width);
            params.onAdjustment(scale);
        };

        if (params.width !== 'device-width') {
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                monaca.viewport.adjust();
            }, false);
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                monaca.viewport.adjust();
            });
        }
    };
}

monaca.viewport.isAndroid = isAndroid;
monaca.viewport.isIOS     = isIOS;
monaca.viewport.adjust    = function() { };
})();
```

---------------------------scall support tabel-------------

this function on javascript support tablet

Answer (score 0):

Simply show the viewport only below certain point.

In this example the viewport instruction shows below 768px

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //below 768px is mobile
    if(screen.width<768)      
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code in head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

and then use this style for mobile device

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print and (min-width: 767px)" href="http://…" />
```

Comment: the ipad will view the screen at 768px not full desktop width

Comment: when you use this code in head tag,when user visited site,page fixed with its width size,for example if ipad width 767px,when user visited by ipad,ipad style load and see site

Comment: i want the ipad to view at 1024px regardless of orientation

Comment: Instead o 767 px you use 1024px,best regards